# If I message a group member or admin will they receive it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

So lets say I joined a Facebook group. If I message somebody from the group (assuming I don't have any mutual friends with that person), will the message land in the "Inbox" or "Other" box? Lets say based on default Facebook settings.

I know for sure it lands in the Other Box if there is absolutely no mutual connection between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lands in the Other box. Inbox is only for those who you have direct friendship with